# How can I get a Xamarin Application (not Forms) to Read the Dark or Light Theme in Settings?

Tags: ios, xamarin, themes, darkmode

When I attempt this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/app-theme?tabs=ios

appTheme is always Light, regardless of my simulator or device Dark setting.

I also tried this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes

But I can't find the code that fetches the Settings theme.

Your help is appreciated!

Thanks!
Larry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIKit.TraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle` contains the current app|view dark/light setting

```
if (this.TraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle == UIUserInterfaceStyle.Dark)
{
   // dark
}
else
{
  // light
}
```

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/UIKit.UITraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiuserinterfacestyle?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12

## Update:

"Still always returning light."

If your `info.plist` contains an `UIUserInterfaceStyle` entry that is set to `Light` it will override the OS setting. Either remove this entry or set it to `Automatic`.

Comment: Still always returning light.  I don't know why.  Help solving this will be rewarded as long as that doesn't violate Stack Overflow policy.  Please email lfeldman65@gmail.com.  Thanks!

Comment: @LarryFeldman Does your `info.plist` have an `UIUserInterfaceStyle` entry in it that is overriding the OS setting and forcing the app into `Light` mode?

Comment: That was it!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Done.  Please check your email for something from Amazon from me.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi!  Did you receive the email I sent to your outlook account?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi!  If you're available by Zoom tonight to help, I have a deadline coming up.  I would really appreciate it!